# Solr how to implement categories in an e-commerce using path hierarchy tokenizer?

Tags: solr, lucene, e-commerce, categories

When I enter this url:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mystore/select?facet.field=category&facet.prefix=Clothes&facet=on&q=*:*
```

I get following facets:

```
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "category":[
         "Clothes", 13,
         "Clothes/Man's", 10,
         "Clothes/Man's/T-shirt", 5,
         "Clothes/Man's/Pants", 4,
         "Clothes/Women's", 3,
         "Clothes/Man's/Pants/Breeches", 2,
         "Clothes/Man's/Pants/Jeans", 2,
         "Clothes/Man's/T-shirt/T-shirt", 2,
         "Clothes/Man's/T-shirt/Polo T-shirt", 2,
         "Clothes/Women's/Turtleneck", 1,
         "Clothes/Women's/leather jacket", 1,
         "Clothes/Women's/Parka", 1,
         "Clothes/Man's/Sweatshirt", 1
        ]},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}
```

Can we change query so that it returns children of Clothes namely **Man's** and **Women's**.
In a nutshell I need result something like this:

```
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "category":[
         "Clothes/Man's", 10,
         "Clothes/Women's", 3
        ]},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The most common and simplest approach in such cases to prepend category level to each category value, i.e.

```
"1-Clothes",
"2-Clothes/Man's",
"3-Clothes/Man's/T-shirt",
"3-Clothes/Man's/Pants",
"2-Clothes/Women's"
```

And apply prefix filter with required category level, for example, `facet.prefix=2-Clothes` for all children categories

Comment: Thanks for answer. But how to make solr to add those numbers?

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box silution here you have to prepare these terms on application side at index time https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SOLR/HierarchicalFaceting Or filter results on application level